When making a Python 2.7 venv in Pycharm, I am getting a syntax error and told it is using Python 3.11? How do I use Python 2.7?
I have a project that is in Python 2.7, it has to be in 2.7 and upgrading is NOT an option so please don't tell me I should just do that, I am using a python package for a specific software that has no Python 3 version.
I can run my unit tests and such just fine, it is able to use Python 2.7 as an interpreter, but I realized that it never created a virtual environment when I tried to use pip in the terminal in pycharm to install a package and it did not recognize the commands pip or even the command python.
Even if I go to C:\Python27 within the terminal in pycharm and type python.exe pip list it says python.exe: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
I attempted to create a new virtual environment using Python 2.7 but got the following error:

The line which is cut off at the bottom of the traceback is a carat pointing to the final quotation mark and saying SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
As you can see, it is executing using C:\Python27\python.exe, but then also says that I am using Python 3.11. Which is especially weird because I don't have Python 3.11 installed on this computer. I have Python 2.7, 3.7, and 3.9, but not 3.11. I am guessing that running using 3.11 instead of 2.7 is the source of the problem.
How do I get it to use Python 2.7 so I can create the venv? I don't need it but it would be very useful.
The question about how to make a Python 2.7 venv in general is not helpful because it does not involve Pycharm. I am specifically asking how to get pycharm to create the venv. I have only used venvs through PyCharm and even if I made one outside of it I wouldn't know how to make PyCharm use it.
Possibly relevant, hopefully not but considering how much grief this has caused me, it might be... You may have noticed that my user folder has an é in it. I actually had to go into the Python 2.7 source code files on my computer and change the encoding from ascii to utf-8 to even get it to run, and that has occasionally caused other problems with PyCharm. Pip has just started throwing a fit when I try to run pip install -e . because of my é. Could that be related?

This question is similar to: How to create a Python 2.7 virtual environment using Python 3.7. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Anerdw it is not helpful because it is not about pycharm. I want pycharm to make the venv for me. I don't know how to get pycharm to use a venv I would make outside of it. I edited the question.

You are aware that you are using unsupported tools. Considering that, you're in no position of being picky: "I don't want to do that", "I only want to do that from PyCharm", ..., well if you want to get your problem solved, of course. Create your VEnv manually and make use of it in PyCharm  (or use an older PyCharm version). Btw, what's the (special) package name?

I'm going to start with the obvious: Python 2.7 has been dead for 4 years now ([Python]: Sunsetting Python 2). Make sure that you clearly mention the reason for sticking to it, otherwise many users might see it as an XY Problem. I saw in a comment from another question that you are working with [Gwyddion]: Gwyddion which indeed doesn't support Python 3.
Now, since Python 2 is no longer supported, packages, tools, ... don't have to support it (some still might, but most will not - as time goes by).
VirtualEnv that is shipped by PyCharm doesn't. Check [SO]: pycharm does not connect to console with python3.8 (@CristiFati's answer) for a similar situation.
Alternatives:
I. Create the Python 2.7 virtual environment manually and "import" it in PyCharm
I'll be explaining the theoretical process with practical examples. There will be scattered snippets from a Cmd console (starting below):

[cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q079004210]> sopr.bat
### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###

[prompt]> :: === Start ===
[prompt]> dir /b
code00.py

[prompt]>



Prerequisites:
There are multiple variants here, so I'll focus on the one I use most. You'll have to have:

A Python 2.7 instance that will be used as a base for creating the VEnv. I'll be referring to it as (like it was a Nix environment variable) ${PY2}

A Python instance with VirtualEnv ([PyPA.VirtualEnv]: Installation - also check [SO]: Python3.7 venv does not Create Virtual Environment Directory (@CristiFati's answer)) installed. This can be the same as the previous one, but I recommend using a n up to date Python 3 version (${PY3}), as there are some prerequisites as well ([PyPI]: pip, and modern Python versions come with it inside). Might be helpful:

[SO]: How to install a package for a specific Python version on Windows 10? (@CristiFati's answer) (important)

[SO]: Creation of Virtual environment with python 3.9 version is executed successfully but python version 2.7 or python version 2.2 shows error (@CristiFati's answer)

[SO]: Install python wheel file without using pip





Create the VEnv
Step(s) detailed in [SO]: Create Windows Python virtualenv with a specific version of Python (@CristiFati's answer).
Typically: "${PY3}" -m virtualenv -p "${PY2}" ${VENV2} where ${VENV2} is the location where you want your VEnv to be created at.
Activate it afterwards:

[prompt]> :: === Create VEnv ===
[prompt]> "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\python.exe" -m virtualenv -p "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\02.07\python.exe" ".\py_0207_pc064_venv"
created virtual environment CPython2.7.18.final.0-64 in 8051ms
  creator CPython2Windows(dest=E:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q079004210\py_0207_pc064_venv, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.3.4, setuptools==44.1.1, wheel==0.37.1
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

[prompt]>
(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> dir /b
code00.py
py_0207_pc064_venv

[prompt]>
[prompt]> ".\py_0207_pc064_venv\Scripts\python.exe"
Python 2.7.18 (v2.7.18:8d21aa21f2, Apr 20 2020, 13:25:05) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^Z


[prompt]> :: Activate VEnv
[prompt]> ".\py_0207_pc064_venv\Scripts\activate.bat"

(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]>
(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> :: Check for PIP
(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> python.exe -m pip freeze
e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q079004210\py_0207_pc064_venv\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip
(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]>
(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> :: @TODO - cfati: Check previous command (error message if PIP not installed, OK otherwise)
(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> (py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> 1



Install PIP in the VEnv
This is an optional step that has to be executed only if PIP is not already there (check the @TODO at the end of the last snippet). Usually it's not required, but exemplifying it anyway (you need PIP to be able to install packages in your VEnv).
Check [AskUbuntu]: How can I find an older version of pip that works with Python 2.7?:

(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> :: === Get (v2.7 compatible) PIP (if not already there) ===
(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> :: Download
(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output ".\get-pip.py"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1863k  100 1863k    0     0  3912k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 3956k

(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]>
(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> dir /b
code00.py
get-pip.py
py_0207_pc064_venv

(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]>
(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> :: Install
(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> python  .\get-pip.py --no-python-version-warning
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting pip<21.0
  Downloading pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     |UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU| 1.5 MB 3.2 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-20.3.4

(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]>
(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> :: Check for PIP
(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> python.exe -m pip freeze --no-python-version-warning

(py_0207_pc064_venv) [prompt]> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0


Now, you should have an usable Python 2.7 VEnv.

Import the new VEnv in PyCharm
Steps (PyCharm related ones) are identical to the ones from [SO]: How to install Python using the "embeddable zip file" (@CristiFati's answer)
After the above steps and PyCharm finishes indexing the files, your new  VEnv is ready to use:


Test the new VEnv from Pycharm
code00.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys


def main(*argv):
    print "Py2.7 specifics:", range(7)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
            " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
            64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
            sys.platform,
        )
    )
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)

Output (PyCharm console):

E:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q079004210\py_0207_pc064_venv\Scripts\python.exe E:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q079004210\code00.py 
Python 2.7.18 (v2.7.18:8d21aa21f2, Apr 20 2020, 13:25:05) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32

Py2.7 specifics: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Done.


Process finished with exit code 0


Also attaching a screenshot:




II. Downgrade your PyCharm installation to a version that is still Python 2.7 compatible
[JetBrains]: Other Versions contains a list of them. For example, v2019.3 should be OK, but you'll have to see it for yourself.
Needless to say that it won't have the features an upper-to-date version has.

III. Modify your PyCharm installation to support Python 2.7
Only mentioning this as a purely theoretical variant, I don't even need to start enumerating the reasons why not to do it. I did it once though: [SO]: Run / Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition? (@CristiFati's answer).
